# mambaforge, conda executable path is empty in pycharm interpreter(Linux mint 20)

Tags: python, pycharm, conda, interpreter

I have installed `conda` environment using `mambaforge` to use `snakemake`. I have followed the instructions of [Snakemake setup tutorial](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/setup.html) to install `mambaforge`. I have created the environment and created a `.py` file, but when I try to run it, it shows the plain code rather than compiling it. When I went to fix it and to add a `Conda environment` in my `PyCharm interpreter` it shows me the following error:
[image]

I tried to add the `conda executable path` by browsing to `mambaforge/bin/conda` but it still shows me the error.

[image]
I also tried to use `which conda` to find the right path, but rather than giving me a path the following is show, I have tried `which conda` in `conda base` environment as well as my setup environment, all it returns is the following:
[image]

I am sure that my conda environment is setup as `conda --version` command shows me the version I have installed.

Answer (score 6):

the conda bin installed with mambaforge is at ~/mambaforge/condabin/conda

Answer (score -1):

I'm not aware of mambaforge conda distribution, I'm using Anaconda / Miniconda distributions with an installed mamba module, so I could create a snakemake environment using terminal (i.e. from command line) and register as Python interpreter in PyCharm Settings as "Conda Environment | Existing environment" (see your first screenshot).

So I suggest you:

1. check whether "Existing environment" works for you, e.g. is able to find you conda environments (e.g base, or others).
2. You could set up Anaconda/Miniconda + mamba + configure PyCharm for using Snakemake with the help of [my detailed guide](https://docs.google.com/document/d/19d_-hPjZ6vXsv30F7tQ8aNrZe7bCTTpsz83Hos0Kt_k) that I use for my students' homework on snakemake.

P.S: I always run snakemake scripts using command line, e.g from terminal bundled into PyCharm, or just system terminal app or on remote server. I don't use PyCharm run configurations for that. As for PyCharm, I use it with [SnakeCharm](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11947-snakecharm) plugin to have a good snakemake & python code editing support